# How to run my iOS app in ios 6 and in ios 7

Tags: ios

How can I run my app developed in iOS 6.1.3 and Xcode 4.6 environment to run in both iOS 6 and in iOS 7 version? More clearly is it possible to create a single ipa file to run in both the above mentioned versions.

Note:

I have already downloaded iOS 7 beta 3 and Xcode DP3.

Comment: You mean that you want to run iOS 7 simulator on iOS 7, right?

Comment: @NtVietHung - I don't get u

Comment: iOS 7 is in Apple's NDA , so you can't discuss about iOS 7 other than apple's developer forum.

Comment: There is a pdf on Apple's developer website titled **iOS 7 UI Transition Guide**, there is a section "Supporting IOS 6" that you might find useful. There is code for a function that returns the iOS version number, so you can do conditional checks on what to load, what to show etc. That document is I think under "iOS Developer Library - Pre-Release", site is still down right now for me, so I don't have the link.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you should not discuss iOS 7 as it is still under Apple's NDA.

In general, if you select the right backwards compatible "Deployment Target" in your targets settings under "iOS Application Target" it should be backward compatible. If you use APIs that would not work on the earlier versions, you should get the appropriate warnings when compiling.